# The package libgdm1 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it

Tags: 18.10

```
:~$ sudo apt install bind9
[sudo] password for ceru: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package libgdm1 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
:~$ sudo apt install dnsutils
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package libgdm1 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

after trying sudo apt update it ended with:

```
Reading package lists... Done                                                  
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/u2t/bleedingedge/ubuntu cosmic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

,can anyone help me resolve this? I'm new to linux and have been having issues with all installs, this was one of the issues. Thank you.

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt update`?

Comment: @Pilot6 that wasn't working either

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `sudo apt update` command.

Comment: What is the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: @Pilot6 i will.

Comment: Please post the full output.

Comment: @Pilot6 its 6000 some letters long so im not allowed to post it?

Comment: You are allowed. But it contains URLs, Post it, then select the text and format it with the `{}` button.

Comment: You can post it at [Ubuntu Pastebin](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com) and provide the link here if the output is too long.

Comment: @Pilot6  https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/3Bq9DMTq2v/

Comment: @Kulfy for your question, https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/V8QqqSHzgs/

Comment: And what is the output of `apt list --installed | grep libgdm1`.

Comment: @Kulfy ,WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

libgdm1/cosmic,now 3.30.1-1ubuntu5 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 3.30.1-1ubuntu5.1]

Comment: fyi: the PPA you get an error for supports only precise (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS/ESM). Your release is cosmic (18.10) so it was wrong to add it (you didn't check it supported your release as it doesn't) and thus should be removed. Your selected mirror is also days behind (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors) so some choose another more reliable mirror for less issues.

Comment: First of all remove the obsolete repository as guiverc suggested. Then run `sudo apt update && sudo apt autoremove --purge libgdm1 && sudo apt install libgdm1`